how to set call back for Databricks Statement Execution SQL API Query?
I m using https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/statementexecution.
using long running queries.my wait time is zero.
queries might take 1 hour and I don't want to do pooling
https://docs.databricks.com/api/workspace/statementexecution/getstatement
the way they explain in above link.
I m using queries with SQL api  not using note book.
do we have any way without pooling we can use some call back mechanism to get notify that
your result is ready and then only I ask for result ?

Databricks does not have a built-in callback mechanism to notify when query results are ready.
You can try the below approach to run a SQL query asynchronously on Azure Databricks using the Databricks SQL API.
SQL query asynchronously:
import requests
import json
import time
DATABRICKS_INSTANCE = '<Your databricks instance>'
TOKEN = '<Personal access token>'
SQL_ENDPOINT_ID = 'SQL END POINT'
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {TOKEN}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
query = {
    "sql": "SELECT * FROM delta.`/FileStore/tables/sample`"
}
response = requests.post(
    f'{DATABRICKS_INSTANCE}/api/2.0/sql/statements',
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps({
        "statement": query['sql'],
        "warehouse_id": SQL_ENDPOINT_ID
    })
)
statement_id = response.json().get('statement_id')
print(f"Statement ID: {statement_id}")

To Query Status:
def check_query_status(statement_id):
    response = requests.get(
        f'{DATABRICKS_INSTANCE}/api/2.0/sql/statements/{statement_id}',
        headers=headers
    )
    return response.json()
while True:
    status = check_query_status(statement_id)
    query_state = status.get('status', {}).get('state')
    
    if query_state in ['SUCCEEDED', 'FAILED']:
        break
    
    print(f"Query status: {query_state}. Checking again in 10 seconds...")
    time.sleep(10)
print(f"Final query status: {query_state}")

Query status: None. Checking again in 10 seconds... Query status: None. Checking again in 10 seconds...

And retrieve the results if the query succeeded:
if query_state == 'SUCCEEDED':
    result_response = requests.get(
        f'{DATABRICKS_INSTANCE}/api/2.0/sql/statements/{statement_id}/result',
        headers=headers
    )
    
    result_data = result_response.json()
    print("Query Results:", result_data)
else:
    print("Query failed.")


this is also pooling /api/2.0/sql/statements/{statement_id}/result'. do we have any other way then pooling
